# jsp page to servlet through ajax and vice versa

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am sending a orderid from jsp page to servlet through ajax and  if the orderid of order table not match it will show an error
message in the same jsp page through which request is made fine. Now my question is a when i sending a valid orderid it should
forward the page to the other jsp page through servlet which is not happing and also not showing any error

jsp page

> ```
>   <input type="hidden" name=cmd  value="single"/>
>     Enter Order No <input type="text" name="oid" id="oidss" /><input type="button" value="Search" id="finduy" />
> ```

jquery code

> $('#finduy').click(function(event){

```
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:"Order",
                style:"full",
                maxRows:12,
                dataType:"json",
                data:{"cmd":"single","oid":encodeURIComponent($('#oidss').val())},

                beforeSend:function(){/*alert("data is sending")*/},
                //problem is here
                success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                        if(data.success){

                }
                else
                    {
                    alert("invalid Order No");
                    $('#oidss').val("");
                    $('#oidss').focus();


                    }

                },
                error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus);
                console.log('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
                 console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
                 console.log("jqXHR.responseText " +jqXHR.responseText);

                  $("#ajaxResponse").html(jqXHR.responseText);
            }
            });
```

servlet code

> if(!(cmd==null)&&cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("single")){

```
        OrderDB odb = new OrderDB();
        Order orders =  new Order() ;
        List<OrderDetail> odetaillist = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
        List<Order> ordercustlist = new ArrayList<Order>();


        String orderids = request.getParameter("oid");


        try {
            orders = odb.getOrdersById(orderids);
            odetaillist = odb.getOrdersDetailsByOrderId(orderids);
            ordercustlist = odb.getOrderFromCustomer(orderids);
            Customer customerinfo = odb.getOrderCustomer(orderids);
            request.setAttribute("OrderSingle", orders);
            request.setAttribute("OrderDetail", odetaillist);
            request.setAttribute("OrderCust", ordercustlist);
            request.setAttribute("CustomerInfo", customerinfo);
            redirect=orderinfo;
            RequestDispatcher view = request.getRequestDispatcher(redirect);
            view.forward(request, response);

            if(orders.getOrderid() == null){
                JsonObject myobj =  new JsonObject();
                myobj.addProperty("success", false);
                PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
                out.print(myobj);
                out.close();
                return;
            }



        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: In your `if(data.success) {` segment of your javascript method, you should send a non-ajax submit to your server and there you will handle the forwarding. Remember that you can't do a forward in an ajax submit.

Comment: thanks  Luiggi Mendoza .. i tried directly through the jsp scriplets it works but i want to know is there any method through ajax i can forward to another servlet

Comment: There are things that you can do in the ajax call and others that you can't. Between the things you can't handle directly with ajax: forward/redirect to another page, upload a file.

Comment: i want to show a alert when user enter wrong 'orderid' by jsp or by servlet

Comment: Messages are handled in view side, not in controller. Looks like you need to understand how to apply MVC pattern. This means that you should handle the message in the ajax response method (success, error, etc).

Comment: thanks Luiggi Mendoza .. i got my answer in your last comment and i handling a message in view side in jsp page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always send a response code back from the servlet and then do a forward . For example you can send success and in which case you can do document.location to new servlet location.

Also uploading files is now possible in html5 using ajax .

Answer (score 0):

I Got The answer thanks user1889970 your trick helps

i created a new checking point whose work is only to check whether orderid is valid if valid it forward to new page or show invalid

jquery code:

```
 $("#find").click(function(event){
    var cname = $('#oidss').val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:"Order",
            style:"full",
            maxRows:12,
            dataType:"json",
            data:{"cmd":"find","oid":encodeURIComponent(cname)},

            beforeSend:function(){/*alert("data is sending")*/},
            success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                    if(data.success){
                        window.location.href='Order?cmd=single&oid='+cname;  
                }
            else
                {
                alert("Invalid Order No.");
                 $('#oidss').val("");
                 $('#oidss').focus();
                }

            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.log('textStatus:' + textStatus);
            console.log('errorThrown:' + errorThrown);
             console.log("Something really bad happened " + textStatus);
             console.log("jqXHR.responseText " +jqXHR.responseText);

        }
        });
    });
```

servlet code:

```
 else if(!(cmd==null)&&cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("find")){

        OrderDB odb         =   new OrderDB();
        Order orders        =   new Order() ;
        JsonObject myobj    =   new JsonObject();

        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        String orderids = request.getParameter("oid");

        try {orders = odb.getOrdersById(orderids);
        if(orders.getOrderid() != null){
            myobj.addProperty("success", true);
        }
        else{
            myobj.addProperty("success", false);
        }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       out.print(myobj);
        out.close();
        return;
    }
```

second part of cmd=single:

```
    if(!(cmd==null)&&cmd.equalsIgnoreCase("single")){

        OrderDB odb = new OrderDB();
        Order orders =  new Order() ;
        List<OrderDetail> odetaillist = new ArrayList<OrderDetail>();
        List<Order> ordercustlist = new ArrayList<Order>();
        String orderids = request.getParameter("oid");


        try {
            orders = odb.getOrdersById(orderids);
            odetaillist = odb.getOrdersDetailsByOrderId(orderids);
            ordercustlist = odb.getOrderFromCustomer(orderids);
            Customer customerinfo = odb.getOrderCustomer(orderids);
            request.setAttribute("OrderSingle", orders);
            request.setAttribute("OrderDetail", odetaillist);
            request.setAttribute("OrderCust", ordercustlist);
            request.setAttribute("CustomerInfo", customerinfo);
            redirect=orderinfo;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```